# Check if the column contains nan, cut and paste to next column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have a dataframe I would like to check the Full_Row column if contains any str nan just cut and paste to new column named 'Minus_row' else keep the cell as it is.

what is the best way to apply it. Thanks in advance

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['Hi', np.nan, 'jak','kind'],
                    'b': ['Hi', 'happy', 'Ali','smile'],
                    'c': [np.nan, 'Ali', 'hak','cute'],
                    'd': ['123456', '123456', '123456','123456']})

df_1['Full_Row'] = df_1.astype(str).apply(', '.join, axis=1)
df_1
```

[image: DataFrame]

Comment: you want to cut full "Full_Row" column value or just the nan part of it to a different column. and also do you wanna keep the Full_Row same as it is?

Comment: @KunalSawant Yes, for example: "Hi, Hi, nan, 123456" this cell in column "Full_Row" has string is "nan", so my condition is if any cell has string "nan" just cut cell and paste it in new column called "Minus_row" . else the cell don't have any string "nan" just keep it as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 In [27]: df_1.loc[ df_1['Full_Row'].astype(str).str.contains('nan') , 'Minus_Row' ] = df_1['Full_Row']



In [28]: df_1.loc[ df_1['Full_Row'].astype(str).str.contains('nan') , 'Full_Row' ] = ''

In [29]: df_1
Out[29]:
      a      b     c       d                   Full_Row                Minus_Row
0    Hi     Hi   NaN  123456                                 Hi, Hi, nan, 123456
1   NaN  happy   Ali  123456                             nan, happy, Ali, 123456
2   jak    Ali   hak  123456      jak, Ali, hak, 123456                      NaN
3  kind  smile  cute  123456  kind, smile, cute, 123456                      NaN
```

Hey you can use str.contains method to check if nan exist in a string as shown above 
hope it helps..